# Database design for smartphone product and its features

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I want to create database for smartphone and its features with feature category

```
    Feature Category
------------------------
|id     name
------------------------
|1      Processor
|2      Memory
|3      Display
|_______________________


Features
------------------------------------------------
|id     name                feature_category_id
------------------------------------------------
|1      Process Speed           1
|2      Process Technology      1
|3      RAM                     2
|4      Screen Size             3
|_______________________________________________

Product 
----------------------------------------
|id     name                Description
----------------------------------------
|1      Moto G4
|2      Iphone 6s plus
|3      Lenovo K4
|______________________________________
```

now i want to store features for particular product for e.g iphone 6s plus product have ram = 2GB, Screensize = 5 inch etc....
But i want best solution for database design.
People keep saying [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Structure_of_an_EAV_table) is a very bad design so any alternative for EAV design.

Comment: Put the features you need to search on in their own columns; put the rest in a JSON string in another column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a [*many-to-many*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between products and features, you will need an additional table to link between them:

```
Products_Features
----------------------------------------
|id   Product    Feature      Value
----------------------------------------
|11      1         1          5''
|22      1         2          2GB
|33      2         1          6''
|33      2         2          3GB
|________________________________________
```

each row here represents a linkage between feature and product, and therefore the number of features per product is not constant as well as the number of products per feature.

Comment: This is still an EAV schema.

Comment: So what? That's the normalization solution for this kind of problems

Comment: Merely providing an alternate name.